# Swift Error 181 Timed Out after .012 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

When I test my Swift app in Xcode, I occasionally get this error:

22:16:49.556 ERROR: 181: timed out after 0.012s (1464 1465); mMajorChangePending=0

I have no idea what it means because it happens rarely and it doesn't seem to cause any issues. I looked around and it appears that it may have something to do with my AVAudioPlayers, but I can't see what I've done wrong with them nor can I tell how they are being affected since my sound plays fine. What could be the cause of this error?

This is where I create the audio players

```
//Player arrays hold multiple players so sounds can be layered on top of each other instead of cutting each other off
var correctPlayerArray:[AVAudioPlayer] = [] //Plays sound when user hits red dot
var wrongPlayerArray:[AVAudioPlayer] = [] //Plays sound when user hits green dot

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GradientBackground.createGradientLayer(self.view, index: 0)
    view.removeConstraints(view.constraints)
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(newView)
    menuView.hidden = true
    menuViewPlayAgain.enabled = false

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(xConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(yConstraint)

    print("New button array size: \(buttonArray.count)")

    //Adds notifications to indicate when app has been closed
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.exitApp), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.exitApp), name: UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object: nil)

    //Adds notifications to indicate when app has been reopened
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loadApp), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    //Instantiates correct player and wrong player
    let correctPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("blopSound", ofType: "wav")!
    let wrongPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("punchSound", ofType: "wav")!
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        for _ in 0..<10
        {
            //var correctPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
            let correctPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: correctPath))
            correctPlayer.volume = soundsVolume
            correctPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            self.correctPlayerArray.append(correctPlayer)
        }

        for _ in 0..<10
        {
            //var wrongPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
            let wrongPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: wrongPath))
            wrongPlayer.volume = soundsVolume
            wrongPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            self.wrongPlayerArray.append(wrongPlayer)
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error: Couldn't create audio players")
    }

    startTimer()
}
```

This is where I play sound

```
func playSound(soundName:String)
{
    if soundsOn
    {
        switch soundName
        {
            case "Correct":
                print("Correct")
                playSoundFromArray(correctPlayerArray)
            case "Wrong":
                print("Wrong")
                playSoundFromArray(wrongPlayerArray)
        default:
                print("Nothing")
        }
    }
}

func resetAudioPlayer(player:AVAudioPlayer)
{
    player.pause()
    player.currentTime = 0
    player.prepareToPlay()
}

func playSoundFromArray(soundArray:[AVAudioPlayer])
{
    var playedSound = false
    var i = 0
    while i < soundArray.count && playedSound == false
    {
        if !soundArray[i].playing
        {
            soundArray[i].play()
            playedSound = true
        }
        i += 1
    }
}
```

Sound is played every time a button is pushed, and since I have about 15 buttons on the screen at once, all of which should be pressed within milliseconds of each other, I created a bunch of audio players to layer on top of each other when sound is played.

Comment: It looks like in your code you are properly preparing the sound file before playing it, but it may be that the sound file has not completed loading. I noticed in my code that if I called prepare immediately before play, I would get that error.